# Design tools for creating skins for Flex 4 components

Tags: apache-flex, flash, skinning, flashcatalyst

I'm looking for a tool to create just the skins for different kinds of Flex 4 components. Are there any?

I'd like to be able to create the components myself and have the designer/artist do the skin, but I don't think they'd like the idea of doing them by writing MXML files.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Catalyst is meant to be that..

it is however - imho - quite hard to use it in a practical environment where there is a workflow like

design > dev > design update > dev > design update > dev

since Flash Catalyst really only works one way.

It's a good attempt from adobe but it's not quite there yet.

You can use it however to do the design slicing yourself, export the result to a separate project and import into your current flex project.

Get a trial and see for yourself.

I don't know of any other "tool". You can export your graphics from the design document and import them as assets manually otherwise.. but that gets tedious quickly..

I'd be interested to know if anyone has a better solution..

Comment: I've tried Catalyst, but it's problem is that it creates whole components and not just their skins. I want to create the components by code in Flash Builder and then have artists skin them in some other tool, like the Catalyst.

Comment: Well, like I said Catalyst doesn't really work for that kind of workflow. You could export the component from catalyst into a separate project, import it into FB and copy the bits that your need to manually create the skin.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new version of Flash Catalyst Panini on Adobe Labs. It has round trip and allows you to use your own custom component from Flash Builder. Also search for the post Jailbreak for Flash Catalyst as this will show you how to work easily between Flash Builder and Flash Catalyst.